# Show div using jquery in PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Hiii everyone,

I just want to show one div if the database value is equal to some value.I tried like this

```
 <?php echo $show['birth_certificate_available']=='Available') { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
       $(".birth").show();
        </script>
        <?php } ?>
```

But the div is not showing.I dont know why its not working.Kindly guide me to correct this issue.

Comment: If the value is not equal to certain value than I am assuming that the div should be hidden, is this the case?

Comment: Begin by writing debug information about `$show`. You need to know first if it goes through your condition, so just use `var_dump($show)` and write down below your code snippet what it displayed on your screen.

Comment: can you read that php statement in plain english?

Comment: is this issue solved? (maybe you forget to mark an answer as solving your question) or the missing jQuery library was not the issue?

Comment: Im asking in general added JQuery library in page.Then why I want to add sepertely in if statemnt inside If i call the library multiple time my bandwidth makes prblm right

Answer (score 1):

Please modify the code accordingly :

```
<?php  if($show['birth_certificate_available']=='Available') { // put a condition?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ // jQuery ready function
              $(".birth").show();
        });
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: 'birth_certificate_available' => string 'Available' (length=9).. This is what im getting..

Comment: you may want to avoid adding a comment right before to close the PHP tag as in `// put a condition?>` because it can confuse wheter or not the `?>` tag is executed

Comment: @Alexandre it's  just a comment.. i put it on for clarification

Comment: @KavyaShree, try to echo some string inside if condition just to know whether we are on right way or not

Comment: Ya I tried with alert inside instead of show hide.Thats working fine

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in `ready()` function as follows,

Assuming you have already imported the relevant jquery lib in your code.

```
<?php echo $show['birth_certificate_available']=='Available') { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
             $(".birth").show();
          });
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

`echo` outputs data to the page. To write a condition, you would like to use `if` statements.

```
<?php if ($show['birth_certificate_available'] === 'Available'): ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.birth').show();
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

*Note*: if jQuery is already linked to your document, remove the `<script src="..."></script>` line. Otherwise, I suggest you to move the `<script src="..."></script>` line right before the `</body>` HTML closing tag to speedup HTML elements loading:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="birth" hidden="hidden">Foobar</div>
        <?php if ($show['birth_certificate_available'] === 'Available'): ?>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.birth').show();
                });
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Note*: I use the `===` equal assertion to force type testing. Whatever, be careful: testing is case-sensitive, whether it is `==` or `===`

> The `div` element must have the `birth` class, must exist and must be hidden in order to successfully `show()` it

### Debug

#### `$show` variable

If this is not working, and in order to debug the `$show` variable, you may want to use `var_dump()` as so:

```
var_dump($show);
```

and ensure it is an array and has the `birth_certificate_available` index defined.

#### Javascript errors

Use the browser console to retrieve javascript errors (such as inexisting `div` elements...)

Comment: I tried this too but div not showing. I used var_dump it shows value correctly.

Comment: You defined the `<div />` element with the class `birth` as something like this: `<div class="birth">`? Does the `<div />` element hidden? Does it exist at the page creation?

Comment: No I defined with <div class="birth">

Comment: If you search in the source code from your browser, is the `div` element existing? Has it the `hidden="hidden"` attribute and value? (or equivalent)

Comment: No @Alex. I searched tht but nothing is like that in browser.

Comment: OK this means you must link jQuery to your document, I edited the answer, do you still have the same error message in the browser console?

Comment: @KavyaShree i think you had already loaded the necessary js files

Comment: Ya I added in PHP page though I added its asking again in if else statement inside

Comment: now is it working? (I added a new `<script src="...">` line above, but in case it works, I suggest you to move it right before closing the `<body>` HTML tag; was this answer the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I missed JQuery reference document so that its not worked.Now I added script document its working.Thanks all who helped me to fix this.